# custom document well vs2017 configuration

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, productivity-power-tools, visual-studio-power-tools

I installed the Productivity Power Tools extension in Visual Studio VS2017.
This extension installed other extensions for me as designed, amongst others Custom Document Well.

I would like to configure Custom Document Well, but I cannot seem to find its configuration page any more.

It used to be under Tools|Options|Productivity Power Tools in previous version of the extension (where all others were bundled into one extension), but the makers of Productivity Power Tools say "there is no longer a need for the page" any more in [their market place page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017).

How can I now configure Custom Document Well extension ?

Comment: This issue has been reported here under Q & A: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.CustomDocumentWell#qna

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed this extension and had the very same doubt. After a little digging I found that the configuration is still under the very same route you describe:

Tools => Options => Productivity Power Tools => Custom Document Well

[image: Productivity Power Tools Configuration]

Maybe it was added in a more recent version (and wasn't there at the time of posting the question). The missing page is the one you select all the active functions, that where separated into individual extensions, so that page doesn't makes sense anymore. But the configuration of each individual component is still there as it always was when the extension was complete.